# How do I access "extra data" stored in XML using JQuery to populate a drop down

Tags: jquery, xml, drop-down-menu, city, multiple-value

Pavel K's answer worked. However, for an unknown reason I needed to change the "data-stationID" to something like "data-sid". May be a mixed case issue?

For anyone else needing more than one piece of data, this line shows how to "stack" more data into the option;

```
$('<option data-stationID="' +$(this).data('sid')+ '" data-lat="' +$(this).data('lat')+'" data-lon="' +$(this).data('lon')+'"  ></option>').text($(this).data('city')).appendTo(city);
```

My XML:

```
<states>
<state name="AK"> 
        <option value="null" data-stationID="null" data-lat="null" data-lon="null" data-city="Select City">Select City</option>
        <option value="326" data-stationID="9450460" data-lat="55.331799" data-lon="-131.626205" data-city="Ketchikan">Ketchikan</option>
        <option value="327" data-stationID="9451054" data-lat="56.246700" data-lon="-134.647003" data-city="Port Alexander">Port Alexander</option>
</state>
<state name="CT"> 
        <option value="null" data-stationID="null" data-lat="null" data-lon="null" data-city="Select City">Select City</option>
        <option value="35" data-stationID="8461490" data-lat="41.361401" data-lon="-72.089996" data-city="New London">New London</option>
        <option value="36" data-stationID="8465705" data-lat="41.283298" data-lon="-72.908302" data-city="New Haven">New Haven</option>
</state>
```

My current code:

```
$('#states').change(function() { // bind a trigger to when the states select changes
        var val = $(this).val(); // hold the select's new value
        var city = $('#cities').empty(); // empty the select of cities and hold a reference in 'city'
        $('state', station_data).filter(function() { // get all states...
            return val == $(this).attr('name'); // find the chosen state
        }).find('option').each(function() { //  Search Between/Within "<option..." for data ending in "city" & create a new option, set its text to the city [name], append to the cities select            
            $('<option>').text($(this).data('city')).appendTo(city);

        })
    });

$('#cities').change(function() { // bind a trigger to when the cities select changes
        console.log($(this).val() );// prints selected city


    });
```

My question is; How do I access the data like "data-stationID" after the user has selected a city? At best, I seem to be only able to get either all stationID's -or only the last stationID inside the option tags.

The idea is that after the user selects the city they'd like information on, I'd have access to all the other "data-*" stored between the option tags so I could query my db [or another php page]

I used the code from [dynamic load data from xml to drop down box with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655340/dynamic-load-data-from-xml-to-drop-down-box-with-jquery) to start this.

Thanks for any help!

Per Ohgodwhy's request, This is my php code that queries my db.

```
fwrite($fh,  "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"); 
fwrite($fh,  "<states>\n");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($states)) {
    fwrite($fh,  "  <state name=\"${row['state']}\"> \n");
    $queryCities="SELECT * FROM locations WHERE state='${row['state']}'";
    $cities=mysqli_query($dbc,$queryCities);
    fwrite($fh, "           <option value=\"null\" data-stationID=\"null\" data-lat=\"null\" data-lon=\"null\" data-city=\"Select City\">Select City</option>\n");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($cities)) {
        fwrite($fh,  "          <option value=\"${row['id']}\" data-stationID=\"${row['stationID']}\" data-lat=\"${row['latitude']}\" data-lon=\"${row['longitude']}\" data-city=\"".StripStuff($row['city'])."\">".StripStuff($row['city'])."</option>\n");
    }
    fwrite($fh,  "  </state>\n\n");
}
fwrite($fh,  "</states>\n");    
fclose($fh);
```

To clarify, I guess I don't know how JQuery handles this info, so I don't know how to access. Also, I can obviously rewrite the php code to export any format if there's a better way I should be formatting the data...

This is my XML import/load function:

```
$.get('test2.xml', function(data) { // get the states.xml file
        station_data = data; // save the data for future use so we don't have to call the file again
        var state = $('#states'); // states select
        $('state', station_data).each(function() { // find states in data & dynamically create a new option element & make its text the value of the "title" attribute in the XML & append it to the states select
            $('<option>').text($(this).attr('name')).appendTo(state);
        });
    }, 'xml'); // specify what format the request will return - XML
```

Using JQuery version: jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Using JQuery Mobile version: jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

Comment: You would simply apply those to the element in some type of `data-attribute` form when you create the elements from the XML parsing. Show the code you use to build your XML so we can correctly formulate an answer.

Comment: You should probably be creating your option tags so they have a `value` attribute with the corresponding data station id (`<option value="..." />`).  Then when an option is selected, you should be able to select the city you need with jQuery using $('city[data-stationID = "'+value+'"]').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not clear way, but you can add option tag from XML directly to select. Try this, it should work:

**Update:**

```
$('#states').on('change', function() { // bind a trigger to when the states select changes
        var state = $(this).val(); // hold the select's new value
        var city = $('#cities').empty(); // empty the select of cities and hold a reference in 'city'
        $('state', station_data).filter(function() { // get all states...
            return state == $(this).attr('name'); // find the chosen state
        }).find('option').each(function() { //  Search Between/Within "<option..." for data ending in "city" & create a new option, set its text to the city [name], append to the cities select            
            $('<option data-stationID="'+$(this).data('stationID')+'"></option>').text($(this).data('city')).appendTo(city);
        })
    });

$('#cities').on('change', function() { // bind a trigger to when the cities select changes
        console.log($(this).children('option:selected:eq(0)').attr('data-stationID') );// prints selected city's attr
});
```

Comment: I replaced my code with the above code and the States drop down was populated, but the City drop down is empty. If i replace    "$(this).appendTo(city);" with the orginal "$('<option>').text($(this).data('city')).appendTo(city);" The city drop down populates, but console.log shows "undefined". Thank you for you assistance!

Comment: @user21850 see my update. My mistake was in that I append jQuery object to select, but not DOM element.

Comment: Now City populates properly, but still getting "undefined" in console.log. If i put console.log($(this).data('stationID')); below "$('option..." I get N undefines [N=number of cities in that state]. However I see what you did with adding the string of data-stationID. That's pretty cool and that's what I believe was I was trying to do!

Comment: Ok! Solved. Something in the way "data-stationID" is parsed did not work with JQuery or JQMobile. -Pavel K's code worked perfectly after I changed "data-stationID" to "data-sid" in my XML.

Comment: @ill13 yes, this shouldn't work with capitols letters in data- attributes. I couldn't leave it unclarified and spent some time to find this in documentation, and found it here http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9066